# how to change the audio bitrate sent by local ip camera?

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, rtsp, recording, ip-camera

How can I change the audio bit rate generated by the openrtsp ? I like to have the same bit rate sent by the camera.

```
./openRTSP "rtsp://user:pass@IP_CAMERA/....."
```

The bit rate sent by the camera i 64 kb/s but when i try to get informations about the audio output of openrtsp i get 352 kb/s.

```
  ffmpeg version git-2014-07-16-aa1d096 Copyright (c) 2000-2014 the FFmpeg developers
      built on Jul 16 2014 18:28:34 with gcc 4.6 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5)
      configuration: --extra-cflags=-I/home/zied/junk/include --extra-ldflags=-L/usr/local/lib/ --enable-gpl --enable-libx264
      libavutil      52. 92.100 / 52. 92.100
      libavcodec     55. 69.100 / 55. 69.100
      libavformat    55. 48.100 / 55. 48.100
      libavdevice    55. 13.102 / 55. 13.102
      libavfilter     4. 11.100 /  4. 11.100
      libswscale      2.  6.100 /  2.  6.100
      libswresample   0. 19.100 /  0. 19.100
      libpostproc    52.  3.100 / 52.  3.100
    [mulaw @ 0x9ac0360] Estimating duration from bitrate, this may be inaccurate
    Guessed Channel Layout for  Input Stream #0.0 : mono
    Input #0, mulaw, from 'audio-PCMA-2.ul':
      Duration: 00:00:48.46, bitrate: 352 kb/s
        Stream #0:0: Audio: pcm_mulaw, 44100 Hz, 1 channels, s16, 352 kb/s
```

Best regards,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

openRTSP does not change the bitrate, it just saves incoming samples to file.

```
44100 * 8 / 1000 = 352.8 kbps
```

If you want a lower bitrate, you need to see if your camera supports other audio formats.

Comment: Thanks @Ralf, <br/>
but when i use ffmpeg with the same audio format , this problem does not exist. What's meant that the problem is on my use of openRTSP. <br/>

`ffmpeg -i "rtsp://user:pass@Camera_IP/..." -vcodec copy -strict experimental -acodec aac  -ab 64k -ar 44100 -f mpegts test.ts` <br/>

with this command, the result is normal audio speed.

Comment: In your case ffmpeg is transcoding the audio to AAC at 64kbps, openRTSP does not have transcoding functionality, it only outputs the received media. Take a look at the SDP received from the camera which will give you the details of the audio format being stream by the server. openRTSP prints this IIRC.

Comment: I tried this command that takes as input the audio file and video file generated by the openRTSP and I used the same settings. But the problem still exists with the audio.
`ffmpeg  -i video-H264-1 -i audio-PCMA-.ul -vcodec copy -strict experimental -acodec aac -ab 64k -ar 44100 -f mpegts test.ts`

Comment: Ok, but your ts file should then contain audio at 64kbps?

Comment: `Input #0, mpegts, from 'test.ts':
  Duration: 00:00:05.14, start: 1.400000, bitrate: 103 kb/s
    Stream #0:0[0x100]: Video: h264 (Main) ([27][0][0][0] / 0x001B), yuv420p(tv, bt709), 320x240, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 90k tbn, 50 tbc
    Stream #0:1[0x101]: Audio: aac ([15][0][0][0] / 0x000F), 44100 Hz, mono, fltp, 65 kb/s`

Comment: As you can see : `Audio: aac ([15][0][0][0] / 0x000F), 44100 Hz, mono, fltp, 65 kb/s` but when i try to play the .ts video `ffplay test.ts` i get a very hight audio speed .

Comment: You need to explain what your problem is: Is it the audio bitrate (as in your original question) or the playback speed in the .ts?

Comment: I thought that the problem is in the bitrate. But as final result I want to have a .ts video with normal audio  speed.

Comment: Please post the SDP from the camera.

Comment: It's that what you mean?  [screenshot of what openrtsp print](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0WWj7-SkdnOYkNRVlc0VVcwWVk/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Yes, exactly, that shows that the sampling rate of the audio is 8kHz, PCMA, mono. Try telling ffmpeg what the input format is according to https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/audio%20types. Try experimenting with "-f alaw" or/and possibly -ar 8000 option.